# Is there a way for users not to be able to download a stored file and just preview it

Tags: firebase-storage

I am hosting some mp3 files for a website, the site showcases music for a producer. I need to be able to let the users listen to the music, but not be able to go to the firebase storage public location. Currently I have the music playing in an  HTML, this obviously requires a source which the user can access and get the file download.

I've been using the getDownloadUrl() method, to get the source link but when you inspect you can see the link to the firebase storage file which will allow the user to download the file.

To let the user listen to the file without being able to download or go to the firebase storage link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to let someone listen to a mp3 stored in Cloud Storage, you effectively have to allow them to download it.  There is no "listen only but no download" function.  Cloud Storage also does not support any audio streaming protocols.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for storage with audio streaming protocols?